# Installing a hadoop cluster between VMs in different hardware machines

Tags: hadoop, virtual-machine, virtualbox, hadoop2

I am responsible for teaching Hadoop to a group of people (let's say 5 people), but without any hardware  available.

Each of them has a laptop, with a quite good amount of memory and processors.

I would like to make them create a Hadoop cluster between their own laptops, which will be connected to the same network.

So far, what I think about is to:

- create a VM image with ubuntu 16 preconfigured (ubuntu 16 is my choice) to be ready for being a cluster node
- ask each of them to run the VM on their computer
- creating a cluster on top of this network of VMs

However, I have some locks:

1/ is it possible to create a private network of VMs located on their different machines, so that the hadoop cluster is isolated from the network that links the physical machines?

2/ What could be wrong with this approach?

3/ Is there a better way for handling this need of setting a Hadoop cluster between different personal machine?

By the way, I am pretty ok with Hadoop installation and so on...

Thanks in advance for your help, suggestions, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to create a private network of VMs located on their different machines

Yes, companies do this all the time with clusters of VMs. Granted, these companies have people with years of experience doing networking setups like this, and have some deep knowledge of firewalls and routing tables

> so that the hadoop cluster is isolated from the network that links the physical machines?

Not without a specific subnet for connecting all the machines. I'm guessing each laptop is sharing the same router, though, and each device has one network interface shared between the host and the VM, so creating this may prove difficult.

> What could be wrong with this approach?

You need to designate at least one machine as the "master" - the namenode, and the ResourceManager. Without this machine, nothing will work. A better approach uses HA deployments, but then you're reliant on "two people"

> Is there a better way for handling this need of setting a Hadoop cluster

Use a free tier/credit of AWS, Azure, or GCP for setting up a cluster. It can start with 2-3 nodes, not 5

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007, the point 2 (about the isolation of the network), is my main problem now. I really would like to make a private network between VMs located in different hardware, but people will use their own laptops and dont have two interfaces on their laptop. All of their laptops will be connected to the same network (the network of the organization, which is a "class A" network).

Comment: I think VirtualBox using NAT or bridge network with the appropriate port forwards could work... Otherwise, I still stand by my suggestion of using a cloud provider... Or if you have enough resources on these machines, I've been able to get a 3 node Hadoop cluster in less than 8 GB of RAM on just one machine